# How to implement shadow in OpenglES 1.x (on iPhone)

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, shadow

How do implement shadow in my OpenglES 1.x scene?
I`ve googled around for hours and couldnt find anything useful. 
Closed I could find was this tutorial (http://www.paulsprojects.net/tutorials/smt/smt.html) but didnt succeed to port it to OpenglES 1.x ..

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: What kind of shadows?  Blob?  Stencil?  Projective?  Self-shadowing?

Comment: I have a house model that I want to cast shadows on itself.. Stencil shadow I guess..

Comment: @user688291: did you come up with a GLES1 solution? I desperately need one myself, so please post it here if you have!