# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 lighting?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, cube

I am new to GLES 2.0. It is really making me nervous because OpenGL ES 1 II just set GL_LIGHTNING1 and then the lighting was set. In GLES 2.0 it is not working. In fact the whole screen is black. So please tell me what should I do with the code below. These are the vertices I am setting:

```
        static float quadrateCoords[] = { // in counterclockwise order:
    // front
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
     0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
    // back
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
     0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
    // left
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
    // right  
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
     0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
     0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,  
    // up  
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
     0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
     0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
    // bottom  
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f
};
static float normal[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,

    -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

    0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,      
    0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,      
    0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,      
    0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f       
};

static float quadrateColors[] = { // in counterclockwise order:
    // front
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
};
```

And the shader code is:

```
        private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
        "uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;\n" +
        "uniform vec3 uLightPos;\n" +

        "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
        "attribute vec4 aColor;\n" +
        "attribute vec4 aNormal;\n" +

        "varying vec4 vColor;\n" +

        "void main() {\n" +
            "vec3 modelViewVertex = vec3(uMVMatrix * a_Position);\n" +
            "vec3 modelViewNormal = vec3(uMVMatrix * vec4(aNormal, 0.0));\n" +
            "float distance = length(uLightPos - modelViewVertex);\n" +
            "vec3 lightVector = normalize(uLightPos - modelViewVertex);\n" +
            "float diffuse = max(dot(modelViewNormal,lightVector), 0.1):\n" + 
            "diffuse = diffuse * (1.0 / (1.0 + (0.25 * distance * distance)));\n" +

            "vColor = aColor * diffuse;\n" + 

            "gl_Position = aPosition * uMVPMatrix;\n" +
        "}\n";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;\n" +

        "varying vec4 vColor;\n" +

        "void main() {\n" +
            "gl_FragColor = vColor;\n" +
        "}\n";
```

And last the draw function:

```
        public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix, float[] mVMatrix) {
    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's aPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
    nNormalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aNormal");
    nColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aColor");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(nNormalHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(nNormalHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer2);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(nColorHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(nColorHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer3);

    muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);        

    muMVMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVMatrix");
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVMatrixHandle, 1, false, mVMatrix, 0);        

    muLightPosHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uLightPos");
    GLES20.glUniform3f(muLightPosHandle, 10.0f, 10.0f, 15.0f);

    // Front
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    // Back
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4);

    // Left
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, 4);

    // Right
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 12, 4);

    // Top
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 16, 4);

    // Right
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 20, 4);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debug like this:
**gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5) + vColor;**

find errors if any, although your shader is correct.

If there are still errors after you have tested for errors (**by directly using colors in place of custom values**) look at this ADS shader

**[How to implement shadow in OpenglES 1.x (on iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518866/how-to-implement-shadow-in-opengles-1-x-on-iphone/11789657#11789657)**

**And another point to remember, disable culling if you have enabled it**

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting a dot product between a projection space vector (`newNormal`), and a world space vector (`lightPos`).

To perform dot product both vectors must be in the same coordinate space. Either provide the normals in world space coordinates (`modelMatrix * aNormal`), or provide the lightPos in projection space (`viewProjectionMatrix * lightPos`).

Comment: i tried it but it didnt work. instead the whole object got black and i couldnt see where it is